# Eclipse Configuration on Ant

Tags: ant, build, eclipse-plugin, installation

I imported `custom_rules.xml` in `build.xml` in my Android program. `custom_rules.xml` triggers both `version.sh` and `version.cmd`, wherein if the operating system is windows, it would execute `version.cmd`, else it would execute `version.sh`.

```
<condition property="versionscript" value="version.cmd" else="version.sh">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

I made sure that `build.xml` has been configured in Eclipse.

However, it does not happen. How would I set up Ant configurations in Eclipse to execute `custom_rules.xml` properly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the `<target name="">`, wherein if the target name can be one of the following: clean, debug, install, etc.

Choose the build file.

Then, on Run As > Ant Build...

On Main, set the buildfile to the location of `build.xml`, then set the base directory to be your project directory.

On targets, choose one of the following: clean, debug, install, etc.

**To run:**
Right click on the build file, then Run as... > Then Run